# Prolog Wordcounter function something wrong

Tags: prolog

When I test this string"No, I am definitely not a pie! I get 6 back as count words but 7 is the right answer. I something case I forgot. But I get the right when i test this string w0w such t3xt... Is some case I forgot. This function shall count numbers of words in a string in Prolog

```
wordcounter([],0).
wordcounter([X],0).
wordcounter([X,Y|Xs],W):- is_alpha(X),\+is_alpha(Y),wordcounter(Xs,W1), W is W1 + 1.
wordcounter([X,Y|Xs],W):- \+is_alpha(X),is_alpha(Y),wordcounter(Xs,W1),W is W1 + 1.
wordcounter([X,Y|Xs],W):- is_alpha(X),is_alpha(Y), wordcounter([Y|Xs],W).
wordcounter([X,Y|Xs],W):- \+is_alpha(X),\+is_alpha(Y),wordcounter(Xs,W).
```

Comment: Could you format your code please?

Comment: wordcounter([],0).
wordcounter([44|Xs],W):-wordcounter(Xs,W1), W is W1 + 1.
wordcounter([X,Y|Xs],W):- is_alpha(X),\+is_alpha(Y),wordcounter(Xs,W1), W is W1 + 1.
wordcounter([X,Y|Xs],W):- \+is_alpha(X),is_alpha(Y),wordcounter(Xs,W1),W is W1 + 1.
wordcounter([X,Y|Xs],W):- is_alpha(X),is_alpha(Y), wordcounter(Xs,W).
wordcounter([X,Y|Xs],W):- \+is_alpha(X),\+is_alpha(Y),wordcounter(Xs,W).

Comment: wordcounter([],0).
wordcounter([44|Xs],W):-wordcounter(Xs,W1), W is W1 + 1.
wordcounter([X,Y|Xs],W):is_alpha(X),\+is_alpha(Y),wordcounter(Xs,W1W is W1 + 1.
wordcounter([X,Y|Xs],W):\+is_alpha(X),is_alpha(Y),wordcounter(Xs,W1),W is W1 + 1.
wordcounter([X,Y|Xs],W):- is_alpha(X),is_alpha(Y), wordcounter(Xs,W).
wordcounter([X,Y|Xs],W):\+is_alpha(X),\+is_alpha(Y),wordcounter(Xs,W).

Comment: wordcounter([],0).
wordcounter([44|Xs],W):-wordcounter(Xs,W1), W is W1 + 1.
wordcounter([X,Y|Xs],W):is_alpha(X),\+is_alpha(Y),wordcounter(Xs,W1), W is W1 + 1.
wordcounter([X,Y|Xs],W):\+is_alpha(X),is_alpha(Y),wordcounter(Xs,W1),W is W1 + 1.
wordcounter([X,Y|Xs],W):- is_alpha(X),is_alpha(Y), wordcounter(Xs,W).
wordcounter([X,Y|Xs],W):\+is_alpha(X),\+is_alpha(Y),wordcounter(Xs,W).

Comment: Does this format above helps?

Comment: Well yes, ok, thanks. I only mean to edit your initial post and follow this format code rules  :)  :
http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Maybe you need cuts in some of your clauses. And you should find out what is wrong with your 5th clause for the case you have two letters: what if the word has only 2 letters?